# Swift polymorphic closure dispatch with struct/protocols

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-protocols, swift-structs

I have a case where I want to register either one argument or no argument closures with a service. There's always an argument available, but for brevity, I want to be able to register no arg closures as well, and then just dispatch the closure without the available argument in that case. Coming from a strong OO and dynamic types background where we love polymorphic dispatch and class inheritance trees and let the types figure themselves out, I can throw the following together:

```
class AbstractAction<T> {
    func publish(value:T) {
        fatalError("you should override this")
    }
}

class NullaryAction<T>: AbstractAction<T> {
    var closure:() -> ()
    override func publish(_:T) {
        closure()
    }
    init(closure:()->()) {
        self.closure = closure
    }
}

class UnaryAction<T>: AbstractAction<T> {
    var closure:(T) -> ()
    override func publish(value:T) {
        closure(value)
    }
    init(closure:(T)->()) {
        self.closure = closure
    }
}

var action:AbstractAction = UnaryAction<Int>(closure: { print("\($0)") })
action.publish(42)
action = NullaryAction<Int>(closure: { print("something happened") } )
action.publish(42)
```

So I see `42` followed by `something happened` in my console. Great.

But I'd like to explore doing this with `struct` and/or `enum`. Value semantics are all the rage. The `enum` approach was relatively straightforward, I think:

```
enum Action<T> {
    case Nullary( ()->() )
    case Unary( (T)->() )

    func publish(value:T) {
        switch self {
        case .Nullary(let closure):
            closure()
        case .Unary(let closure):
            closure(value)
        }
    }
}

var action = Action.Unary({ (arg:Int) -> () in print("\(arg)") })
action.publish(42)
action = Action<Int>.Unary( { print("shorthand too \($0)") } )
action.publish(42)
action = Action<Int>.Nullary({ print("something happened") })
action.publish(42)
```

To do a `struct` approach, I it is my understanding that I should use a protocol to capture common interface of `publish(value:T)`. But that's where things get confusing, because protocols apparently can't be mixed with generics? I tried:

```
struct NullaryAction<T> {
    typealias ValueType = T
    var closure:() -> ()
}

struct UnaryAction<T> {
    typealias ValueType = T
    var closure:(T) -> ()
}

protocol Action {
    typealias ValueType
    func publish(value:ValueType)
}

extension NullaryAction: Action {
    func publish(_:ValueType) {
        self.closure()
    }
}

extension UnaryAction: Action {
    func publish(value:ValueType) {
        self.closure(value)
    }
}

var action:Action = UnaryAction(closure: { (arg:Int) -> () in print("\(arg)") })
action.publish(42)
action = UnaryAction<Int>(closure: { print("shorthand too \($0)") } )
action.publish(42)
action = NullaryAction<Int>(closure:{ print("something happened") })
action.publish(42)
```

This just produces a lot of errors at the bottom. I had tried to do the extensions as generics (e.g. `extension NullaryAction<T>:Action`), but it told me that `T` was unused, even though I had placed the `typealias` expressions in the extensions.

Is it possible to do this with struct/protocol? I'm happy with the enum solution, but was disappointed I couldn't realize it with the struct/protocol approach.

Comment: Protocols and generics can be quite tricky in Swift. Maybe the answer in this thread can help you: http://milen.me/writings/swift-generic-protocols/ (see also forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7350). Both these are however relating having a generic return type of some protocol function, but maybe you can work your dynamic type magic to work something out :) I'm interested to know the outcome, for your specific example (tried to fix something but failed rather miserably...)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the fact that you want to cast your structs to their protocols (by using `var action: Action = UnaryAction {...}`), I'm assuming you don't need the `publish` method to have the right signature upon evoking it.

In other words, by declaring your `Action` protocol with a `typealias`, the compiler is expecting to specialise the `publish` method for each instance of your structs.

This means that you have two options:

1. **Remove the type casting:**

Example:

```
var action /*removed the :Action type casting */ = UnaryAction<Int>(closure: { (arg:Int) -> () in print("\(arg)") })
action.publish(42)
action = UnaryAction<Int>(closure: { print("shorthand too \($0)") } )
action.publish(42)
var anotherAction = NullaryAction<Int>(closure:{ print("something happened") }) //need to use another variable for this last one
anotherAction.publish(42)
```

This solution makes your `publish` methods also have the same signature that your structs have. If your struct is specialised to work with `Ints`, then you'll have `.publish(value: Int)`.

2. **Make the protocol non-generic**

Example:

```
protocol Action {
    func publish(value:Any)
}

struct NullaryAction<T>: Action {
    let closure: () -> ()
    init(closure: () -> ()) {
        self.closure = closure
    }
    func publish(value:Any) {
        self.closure()
    }
}

struct UnaryAction<T>: Action {
    let closure: (T) -> ()
    init(closure: (T) -> ()) {
        self.closure = closure
    }
    func publish(value:Any) {
        self.closure(value as! T) //Need to type cast here
    }
}

var action: Action = UnaryAction<Int>(closure: { (arg:Int) -> () in print("\(arg)") })
action.publish(42)
action = UnaryAction<Int>(closure: { print("shorthand too \($0)") } )
action.publish(42)
action = NullaryAction<Int>(closure:{ print("something happened") })
action.publish(42)
```

This solution allows you to keep on type casting, but your `publish` methods will all have the same signature (`.publish(value: Any)`). You also need to account for that upon executing the closure.